# Changing line type for boundary of two vectors?

Tags: qgis, style

I currently have two vector shapefiles containing polygons representing health geographies of England and Wales.

[image]

I would like to be able to change the line type for the boundary/lines between the orange and purple regions (Wales and England), in terms of thickness, colour, solid/striped/dot dash etc.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the line style **only** at this boundary between orange and purple ?

Comment: Guess he/she does. Easiest solution in my opinion: New line-layer, digitize that border, style it properly and put it on top of everything

Comment: @snaileater correct

Comment: if those borders are accurare topologically, you might get a linestring as a return geography from both layers' intersection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a virtual layer to automatically derive the desired geometry.

Go to the menu `layer / add layer / add/edit virtual layer` and enter the query, replacing `a` and `b` by your region layer name

```
select  st_intersection(a.geometry,b.geometry) 
from a, b
where st_intersects(a.geometry,b.geometry)
```

Then style this layer with an adequate line symbol

[image]

Comment: That is extremely clever - is it possible to do that between polygons in the same shapefile which share a boundary?

Comment: @EdRollason Yes, for that you would refer twice to the same layer and use an alias (`... from mylayer a, mylayer b ...`)

Comment: @JGH I'm unfamiliar with how to use such an alias.  A Google search didn't help.   Perhaps you could elaborate your example?  Thanks much!

Comment: @StuSmith It is simpler (=less typing) to use the alias rather than the full table name, but it is not mandatory. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)